# cannot find -lpcre2-8

Tags: rstudio, ld

i am trying to install `rjava` in Rstudio following libraries show error `-lpcre2-8, -lbz2, -lz`

Any solution to solve these? Not getting any luck on other sites and there solutions provided by various geeks.
System : ubuntu-20.04

error code:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcre2-8
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbz2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install needed packages using

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre2-dev libbz2-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Comment: solved thank you so much @N0rbert

Comment: sudo apt-get install r-cran-rjava try this as well, helps